# Bisecting a mesh along a curved path defined within another mesh

Tags: modeling, boolean-modifier, stl

I am trying to make a device mount that will clamp around the rails of a bike seat. I have the shape of the rails (blue) from an imported STL file and have Boolean differenced them to create the corresponding hollow spaces in this block (yellow). I now need to divide the block into a top and bottom half that will clamp around the rails. The cut line needs to follow the centerline of the rail so that each half can fit around the rails. So far I have tried to recreate the rail shape as a Bezier curve but I could not perfectly capture the shape and I need the fit to be exact. TIA!

[image]

Comment: 1.. how was the STL generated? could you get your half-tubes from the same source? 2.. Could you share an example on https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can see its horrible topology?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved -- I was able to better refine the hand-drawn bezier curve, extrude to a surface and then a mesh, then use for Boolean modifier.